# How to get the hWnd of Window instance?

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF application has more than one window, I need to be able to get the hWnd of each Window instance so that I can use them in Win32 API calls.

Example of what I would like to do:

```
Window myCurrentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
IntPtr myhWnd = myCurrentWindow.hWnd; // Except this property doesn't exist.
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the Hwnd of a WPF Popup control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815121/is-it-possible-to-get-the-hwnd-of-a-wpf-popup-control)

Comment: @HansPassant: The other question concerned popup controls, not actual windows. (Yes, this question was also indirectly answered within it, but it is not a duplicate.)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[`WindowInteropHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms618134) is your friend. It has a constructor that accepts a `Window` parameter, and a `Handle` property that returns its window handle.

```
Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
IntPtr hWnd = wih.Handle;
```

Answer (score 24):

Extending on Douglas's answer, if the `Window` has not been shown yet, it might not have an HWND. You can force one to be created before the window is shown using [`EnsureHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.ensurehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
var window = Window.GetWindow(element);

IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle();
```

Note that `Window.GeWindow` can return `null`, so you should really test that too.

Comment: I feel like the checks would rarely be needed, generally you'd just place your code where you're sure the window handle exists. The most obvious would be the Loaded event