# C++ C# wrapper related. How do I get a hwnd from C# window and pass it to C++?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, game-engine, directx-11

I am working on a game engine right now. I am planning to use WPF as my level editor UI.

I am going to wrap the base engine functionality like video tutorial below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqsj__ZVm-c

or using swig

http://www.swig.org/

I am wondering, how can I pass the window handler from WPF to the unmanaged c++? I am using DirectX11.

something like:
class GraphicSystem
{
....
void Initialize( hwnd window);
}

"Draw implementation"

```
void Initialize(hwnd window)
{
    // Create the Direct3D object.
    m_D3D = new D3DClass;

    // Initialize the Direct3D object.
    result = m_D3D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, VSYNC_ENABLED, hwnd,                   
                               FULL_SCREEN, SCREEN_DEPTH, SCREEN_NEAR);
}
```

So I can manage the viewport ("window") properties such as size from wpf.

Comment: WPF does not like window handles very much.  You need to create a host for such a window, the MSDN library article [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752055%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for getting the HWND of your WPF app: 
[How to get the hWnd of Window instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675305/how-to-get-the-hwnd-of-window-instance)

I guess you can use Interop to pass the value to the C++ code.