# C# screenshot another application

Tags: c#, background, screenshot

i would like to take a screenshot for a form of an opened application which is not on top without bringing this app on top to capture screenshot of the form !
i want to do it on C#
i have searched a lot and i found nothing.
would you please give any code hints?

Comment: If a "screenshot" is an image of all or part of a screen, then how do you suppose this would work?

Comment: thank you guys i will edit my question right now

Comment: This sounds like it will involve UI Automation and/or an accessibility API. Which operating systems are you interested in?

Answer (score 0):

The [PrintWindow API (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869(v=vs.85).aspx) method can do that. You can use the API from C# using P/Invoke. The website pinvoke.net has the [definition you need](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.printwindow).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hDC, uint nFlags);
```

You'll need a window handle which you can get [like in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675305/how-to-get-the-hwnd-of-window-instance).