# How to get HWND for window

Tags: c#, wpf, hotkeys

I have this piece of code that works on `Winform`:

```cs
public class GlobalHotkey
{
    private int modifier;
    private int key;
    private IntPtr hWnd;
    private int id;

    public GlobalHotkey(int modifier, Keys key, Form form)
    {
        this.modifier = modifier;
        this.key = (int)key;
        this.hWnd = form.Handle;
        id = this.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Register()
    {
        return RegisterHotKey(hWnd, id, modifier, key);
    }

    public bool Unregiser()
    {
        return UnregisterHotKey(hWnd, id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return modifier ^ key ^ hWnd.ToInt32();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
}
```

And after `InitializeComponent` I just initiate it this way:

```cs
ghk = new GlobalHotkey(Constants.CTRL + Constants.SHIFT, Keys.A, this);
```

I have a WPF project and I want to use the same class, so I try to change the constructor this way:

```cs
public GlobalHotkey(int modifier, Keys key, System.Windows.Window form)
{
    this.modifier = modifier;
    this.key = (int)key;
    this.hWnd = form.Handle;
    id = this.GetHashCode();
}
```

But I have a compile-time error at this line:

```
this.hWnd = form.Handle;
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Window' does not contain a definition for 'Handle' and
>   no accessible extension method 'Handle' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the hWnd of Window instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675305/how-to-get-the-hwnd-of-window-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Using WPF, the [WindowInteropHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper?view=netframework-4.8) class exists to get the required handle.

> Members of this class allows the caller to have internal access to the
>   Win32 HWND and the parent HWND of a WPF Window.

After creating a `WindowInteropHelper`, you can use it's handle like done with a `Form`. In your case, the constructor should look like this:

```
public GlobalHotkey(int modifier, Keys key, Window window)
{
    this.modifier = modifier;
    this.key = (int)key;
    //Use handle to register or unregister hotkey
    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
    this.hWnd = helper.Handle;
    id = this.GetHashCode();
}
```

Note that you can also pass `IntPtr.Zero` as handle if the hotkey does not needs to be received by a specific window.

Comment: Where i need to use this 2 lines ?

Comment: This replaces the win forms `this.hWnd = form.Handle`

Comment: My function signature is still GlobalHotkey(int modifier, Keys key, Form form) and i have compile error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Hotkeys.classes.core.GlobalHotkey' to 'System.Windows.Window'

Comment: Sure, you need also to replace the `Form` by a WPF `Window`.