# How to get handle of the scroll bar from WPF window by interoperability?

Tags: c#, wpf, interop

Facing issue with getting control handle of the WPF window, Is any solution for this?

am not sure about the below procedure is the right one

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindow")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

//windowObj is the object of WPF window which contains the scroll bar
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(windowObj).Handle;
  if (windowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
  {
     //GW_CHILD=5

     IntPtr hScroll = GetWindow(windowHandle, GW_CHILD);
     if (hScroll != IntPtr.Zero) // always getting 0
     {   
     }
  }
```

**windowObj** is the object of a WPF window which contain the scroll bar control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the Hwnd of a WPF Popup control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815121/is-it-possible-to-get-the-hwnd-of-a-wpf-popup-control)

Comment: which hWnd do you pass in? how do you obtain it - `WindowInteropHandler`? I'd recommend to use an inspector tool (like Spy++) to verify that the hierarchy of window handles really is organized in the way you expect it to be. especially WPF is known for shims and layers that are not visible, and painted "lightweight" stuff that does not have a handle on its own.

Comment: WPF scrollbars have no handles, as well as other WPF controls. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is "scroll bar control"? What is `windowObj`? What you are trying to achieve? You can get a handle of window, but controls aren't windows in wpf. @Rekshino, popup is special.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response, I found some of them are also saying WPF controls have no handle only we get the handle for the WPF window